# Processing two XML documents to find results

Tags: c#, xml

I have some XML documents:

events.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<events>
  <event>
    <id>9</id> 
    <region>3</region> 
    <region>12</region> 
    <region>29</region> 
  </event>
  <event> 
    <id>7</id> 
    <region>1</region>
    <region>12345</region>
  </event>
  <event> 
    <id>3</id> 
    <region>12</region>
    <region>39</region> 
    <region>56</region> 
  </event>
  <event> 
    <id>8</id> 
    <region>8</region> 
    <region>123</region> 
    <region>456</region>
  </event>
  <event> 
    <id>4</id> 
    <region>999</region> 
    <region>888</region> 
    <region>777</region> 
  </event>
</events>
```

exposure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<companies>
  <company> 
    <id>6</id>
    <region>3</region>
    <region>9</region> 
    <region>8</region>
    <region>11111</region> 
    <region>12</region> 
  </company>
  <company> 
    <id>4</id> 
    <region>3</region> 
    <region>6</region> 
    <region>7</region> 
    <region>12345</region> 
  </company>
  <company> 
    <id>9</id> 
    <region>1</region> 
    <region>2</region> 
    <region>3</region> 
  </company>
</companies>
```

I need to write a program to process the two files:

> For each event in the event file the program should write out the
>   event number followed by the set of companies it affects in the
>   exposure file. The list of companies should be written out in
>   ascending company number.

Given the sample files, the output should be something like this:

```
 9 4 6 9

 8 6

 7 4 9

 3 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a little bit of LINQ in your life.

```
var eventsDoc = XDocument.Load(@"events.xml");
var exposureDoc = XDocument.Load(@"exposure.xml");

var companies =
   (from c in exposureDoc.Descendants("company")
    let id = (int)c.Element("id")
    orderby id
    select new
    {
        Id = id,
        Regions = new HashSet<int>(
            from r in c.Elements("region")
            select (int)r),
    }).ToList();
var events =
    from e in eventsDoc.Descendants("event")
    let id = (int)e.Element("id")
    orderby id descending
    select new
    {
        Id = id,
        Regions = from r in e.Elements("region")
                  select (int)r,
    };
foreach (var evnt in events)
{
    var affectedCompanies =
        from c in companies
        where c.Regions.Overlaps(evnt.Regions)
        select c.Id;
    if (affectedCompanies.Any())
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", evnt.Id, String.Join(" ", affectedCompanies));
}
```

If you're using .NET 3.5, you'll need to change the query in the body of the loop a bit.

```
var affectedCompanies =
   (from c in companies
    where c.Regions.Overlaps(evnt.Regions)
    select c.Id.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Since I have nothing better to do... this one's free.

Comment: thanks for this Jeff...bit of a newbie to linq but it looks pretty efficient...just getting a couple of errors on the arguments for output...                                                       Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Error 2 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'string[]'          Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: See the last part of my answer, it sounds like you're using .NET 3.5 so you'll need to make a few adjustments.

Comment: excellent Jeff, that worked a treat! as you suspected i was working off 3.5, really enjoying getting to grips with Linq here, it really is so efficient...Hail Jeff - King of the Linq!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use XInclude to effectively combine these two together into a single document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<combination xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="events.xml" />
    <xi:include href="exposure.xml" />
</combination>
```

After that,

1. Read in the "combined" document using XmlDocument
2. Use SelectNodes to pull in the list of events (XPath: `//event/id./')
3. Use SelectNodes to pull in the list of regions for each event
4. Use SelectNodes to pull in the companies affected by each region

There is plenty of documentation on how to use the XmlDocument framework and XPath. For example, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544391/xmldocument-selectnodesxpath-order-of-result).